# Is there statistics on self-harm in France?

Tags: mental-health, statistics

I'm having a hard time finding statistics related to self-harm in France (number of persons, sex, percentage related to other mental health issues, age,...). I only found a few old press articles with not a lot of sources and numbers. 
Does anyone know if such studies were conducted in the last 10 years for the french population?

I'd also be very grateful if someone could provide me with stats or studies for other contries, even though I'd rather focus on France.

Comment: Normally this sort of data is conducted by department of health, or local medical journals which would be in French.

Comment: The *German Federal Office for Statistics (Statitstisches Bundesamt or DESTATIS)* annually publishes reports about self-harm related incidents (or *SelbstVerletzendes Verhalten* (SVV). Taken from the 2015 data set published in 2017 and thus being the latest release [(available for download here)](https://www.destatis.de/DE/Publikationen/Thematisch/Gesundheit/Gesundheitszustand/UnfaelleGewaltKinderTabellenband.html;jsessionid=9FCCB961E4BFD9A9AA15E9331A1B87CB.InternetLive1). This is a massive document, and it'd take me ages to read through it. I'm looking for secondary literature, and for french

Comment: [cont'd] data sets. But as Graham pointed out, one would need to be able to speak french for that. // Does a link to the raw data suffice, or do you want some interpretation and analysis of the data as well?

Comment: Another [European resource](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi9vquBha7aAhUPa1AKHfGMBcMQFgg3MAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fec.europa.eu%2Feurostat%2Fstatistics-explained%2Findex.php%2FMental_health_and_related_issues_statistics&usg=AOvVaw1iUBIfskZNkszgD4V7LV0i), but probably not exactly what you were looking for because very undetailed, opposed to the German report which lists and includes everything (with the downside of the understanding of the document being quite difficult)

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma I'm fine with raw data :) Thank you very much for the german data set !